# How to inject repository into a service

Tags: symfony

I would like to inject a repository into a service. My first step was to define the repository as service, like:

```
<service id="app.repository.user" class="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository">
        <factory class="doctrine" method="getRepository" />
        <argument>AppBundle:User</argument>
</service>
```

In second step i inject the defined repository service

```
<service id="app.registration_handler" class="AppBundle\Utils\RegistrationHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="security.password_encoder" />
        <argument type="service" id="app.repository.user" />
    </service>
```

But i get this error message:

```
Attempted to load class "doctrine" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

I remember that this works in previous versions, have someone the same issue and a hint for me?

I'm using Symfony 3.01

Update:
I solve my issue. I made the mistake to define a class instead of a service, now it workts.

```
<factory service="doctrine" method="getRepository" />
```

Comment: Not sure, why someone would downvote this... just add the answer yourself should someone stumble upon the same ;)

Comment: @JovanPerovic In my opinion this question (and the relative answer) is pretty useless for the SO community because is a simple user error (caused by a distraction). Symfony's docs explain clearly how to inject "something" into a service.

Comment: Yes, but `Doctrine` repository is kind of special case because you need to utilize a factory. However, you're right about user-error and usefulness...

Answer (score 2):

**Since 2017 and Symfony 3.3+** there is quite easy way to do this.

**Check my post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)** for more general description.

To your code - all you need to do is create own repository as service.

#### 1. Create own repository without direct dependency on Doctrine

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class UserRepository
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
    }

    // add desired methods here
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->repository->findAll();
    }
}
```

#### 2. Add config registration with [PSR-4 based autoregistration](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    AppBundle\:
        resource: ../../src/AppBundle
```

#### 3. Injecting repository to any service or controller is now EASY

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository;    

class MyController
{
    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = userRepository
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another idea is to use the ["expression language"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) into service configuration

```
<service id="app.registration_handler" class="AppBundle\Utils\RegistrationHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="security.password_encoder" />
        <argument type="expression">service('doctrine').getRepository('AppBundle:User')</argument>
</service>
```